# Неизвестное количество элементов поместить в одну таблицу

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

имеется 5 таблиц. 
 1. музеи с атрибутами id, координаты ...
 2. памятники ...
 3. мемориалы ...
 4. Кафе
 5. Гостиницы

Необходимо создать таблицу, которая будет содержать в себе маршрут (список из 3х таблиц выше). Как спроектировать эту таблицу? Я не знаю сколько музеев выберет пользователь ,сколько памятников и т.д. 
Если хранить id, то как определить какой  id к какой таблице относится?

В голову пока приходит только вариант, к каждой таблице добавить супер-уникальный-id который не будет повторяться ни в одной из таблиц.

Либо же ограничить пользователя и не дать выбрать больше 10 объектов из одной таблицы, а таблицу маршрут создать с атрибутами id, muzei1, muzei2, ... , muzei10, pamyatnik1, ... , pamyatnik10, ... , memorial10. Но тогда в таблице будет оч много NULL Значений.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как более грамотно спроектировать таблицу Маршруты.

Comment: Могу подсказать шикарное решение: задите в Яндекс и наберите "основы проектирования баз данных"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, непонятно зачем у вас разные таблицы для объектов, если хватит одной:

```
create table `objects`
(
    `id`      int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    `type`    enum('museum','monument','memorial'),
    `name`    varchar(255),
    `comment` text,
    `geo_x`   float, --- или что вам нужно
    `geo_y`   float,
    key(`type`)
);
```

Дальше, маршруты и их точки:

```
create table `routes`
(
    `id`       int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    `name`     varchar(255),
    `comment`  text 
);

create table `route_points`
(
    `id`         int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    `route_id`   int unsigned,
    `object_id`  int unsigned,
    `order`      int unsigned,
    key(`order`)
);
```

Ну и выборка точек для маршрута, поля подставьте сами:

```
select 
    route_points.id as point_id,
    objects.id as object_id,
    objects.name,
    objects.geo_x,
    objects.geo_y
from
    route_points 
inner join
    `objects`
on
    route_points.object_id = objects.id
where
    route_points.route_id = $route_id
order by
    route_points.order    
;
```

Comment: Разные таблицы потому что атрибуты у них немного отличаются, н-р у памятников нет времени работы и выходных и т.п.

Comment: Если таблицы разные, то route_points будет 
create table `route_points`
(
    `id`         int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    `route_id`   int unsigned,
    `museum_id`  int unsigned,
    `memorial_id`  int unsigned,
    `monument_id`  int unsigned,
    `order`      int unsigned,
    key(`order`)
); ?

Comment: Вы вполне можете заложить в таблицу объектов все поля, и неиспользуемые (в разных типах объектов) просто не использовать. Любое решение с размножением таблиц объектов в этой ситуации будет заведомо кривым.

Comment: В крайнем случае - сделать в таблице объектов какое-нибудь поле `data`, где хранить дополнительные данные, характерные только для этого типа.

Comment: для себя я бы конечно сделал все в одну таблицу. Да и сделал все в одну таблицу. Но так нарушается нормализация. Да и в универе сказали, что бд из 2х таблиц - недостаточно. значит проект маленький.

Comment: Значит, надо перебираться из Индии (или Китая?) в какую-нибудь другую страну :)